# Can 2 Spark job use a single HDFS/S3 storage simultaneously?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop

I'm a beginner in Spark. Can I have 2 spark jobs to use a single HDFS/S3 storage at the same time? One job will write latest data to S3/HDFS and other will read that along with input data from another source for analysis.

Comment: Your title says: "Can 2 Spark job use a single HDFS/S3 storage simultaneously?"  but your description referencing multiple sources.  Is your question about access 1 data source from two jobs or [something else]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can be writing and reading to the same data source.  Data will only be present once writes are completed.(In both HDFS/S3)

Comment: The question is asking about using different sources. Your answer says "same"

Comment: Hmm the title of the question states: "Can 2 Spark job use a single HDFS/S3 storage simultaneously?"  so I thought the question was about 2 jobs accessing the same source.

Comment: @MattAndruff Yes you are right. My question is "Can I read data from S3 in one Spark Job and write to the same S3 from another Job"

Answer (score 0):

In order to use both file systems, you need to include the protocol for the files.

e.g. `spark.read.path("s3a://bucket/file")` and/or `spark.write.path("hdfs:///tmp/data")`

However, you can [use S3 directly in place of HDFS via setting `fs.defaultFS`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html)